# Pandas Series Plot and GridSpec

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having problems with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.arange(10)
yy = np.arange(10)
zz = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,6)
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0:2])
zz.plot(ax=ax0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,2:4])
zz.plot(ax=ax1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0,4:])
#plt.plot(xx,yy)
zz.plot(ax=ax2)
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.close()
```

I get the error:

```
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4
```

However, when I substitute the

```
zz.plot(ax=ax2)
```

with

```
plt.plot(xx,yy)
```

it works fine. Can anyone help me understand why Pandas generates this error?

Comment: your example works fine for me

Comment: I discovered that it is linked to my version of pandas: 0.16.2. After reverting to version 0.15.2, this code works. However, I still had an issue with missing xlabels when using gridspec - that was resolved by reverting to pandas 0.15.1. Now all my plots look great...